# How to start a visible process

Tags: vb.net, process

I have the following code to start the program R (even though I think that the program is not relevent for the problem here) and run a script:

```
Public Shared Sub RunRScript(rCodeFilePath As String, rScriptExecutablePath As String, args As String)

    Dim file As String = rCodeFilePath
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Dim info = New ProcessStartInfo()
        info.FileName = rScriptExecutablePath
        info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(rScriptExecutablePath)
        info.Arguments = rCodeFilePath & " " & args

        info.RedirectStandardInput = False
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        info.UseShellExecute = False
        info.CreateNoWindow = True

        Using proc = New Process()
            proc.StartInfo = info
            proc.Start()
            result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
            proc.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("R Script failed: " & result, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Problem is, if there is an error in the script I run within R I dont get an error message because the instance is invisible. I tried to make it visible with

```
.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
```

in all combinations of .UseShellExcecute and .CreateNoWindow but this is not working. Could anyone help me to can make my process visible?

Comment: It makes little sense to post code with CreateNoWindow = True and then ask how to make the window visible.  There is no window.

Comment: Use StandardError to get the error.

Comment: I used standarderror and it worked. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sarvesh, repost as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are redirecting StandardInput and StandardOutput, you should now redirect StandardError to trap the errors also.
More info available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)